# Проблемы с функцией сhmod

Tags: php, javascript

Есть некая форма в которую записываются цифровые значения вида "777", "644" и т.д. потом значение этой формы отправляются яваскриптом в пхп скрипт и передаются функции chmod, но для этой функции будет правельным следующий синтаксис:

```
chmod($name, 0777);
```

а значение для функции передаётся в виде трёх цифр, а не четырёх:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$chm = $_POST['chm']; // 777 например
chmod($name, $chm);
```

как из 777 сделать 0777 ? пробовал разные варианты типа:

```
$cmd = '0'.$cmd;
```

но права на файл ставились совсем другие, может есть решение на js, как нибудь добавлять ноль к числу из формы, перед отправкой

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас есть доступ к командной оболочке? В подавляющем большинстве, режим доступа к файлу или директории, может быть изменен только его **владельцем**.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы видимо не знаете или забыли, что права на файлы задаются в восьмеричной СИ.

**UPD:** Примеры преобразований чисел на JS и PHP.

js:

```
var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('own_input_number'),8);
```

php:

```
$chmod = decoct($_POST['chm']);
```

Comment: так тоже пробовал, как на яваскрипте так и на пхп

Answer (score 0):

Да, параметр доступа, переданный функции вторым параметром - есть ни что иное, как число в 8-ричной системе счисления( а не в 16-ричной, как утверждает [[@evlanoff](/users/7877/evlanoff)](/users/7877/evlanoff) ):

```
<?php
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 755);   // десятичное, неверный способ
chmod("/somedir/somefile", "u+rwx,go+rx"); // строка, неверный способ
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // восьмеричное, верный способ
?>
```

---

Это, so bad...

```
    $cmd = '0'.$cmd;
```

Вот почитайте об этом поподробнее **[здесь](http://www.php.su/functions/?chmod)**.

Comment: это я знаю, я же и спрашиваю как из 755 получить 0755 например, из формы берётся только десятичное число

Comment: Тогда смотрите эту функцию[** математическую функцию конвертации**][1]:

[1]: http://www.php.su/functions/?decoct

Comment: пробовал, из 777 с помощью этой функции 0777 не получить